# Scale Range Question

Tags: scales, range

I have a very simple question for those who are familiar with scale ranges. I am interpreting a psych assessment taken for an assessment class. The assessment includes 24 different wellness scales. The scales are said to be "equalized to a range between 25-100." I'm not quite sure what this quote means. Thanks for any feedback you can give!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Wiki page. :)